# Spring ModelMapper error: Mapping already exists for controller

Tags: spring, hibernate, modelmapper

I am getting data from my form through a DTO and mapping it to my Hibernate entity. I wanted to skip a date field as the incoming data is all strings and I need to convert the string field into a date separately from other fields. The rest of the fields are to be directly mapped from the incoming DTO. The process works fine for the first request, but on subsequent requests, the following exception is thrown:

```
     1) A mapping already exists for com.ibm.calypso.entity.WmCompIdfn.setEffStartDate().

1 error
    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.toConfigurationException(Errors.java:250)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.TypeMapImpl.addMappings(TypeMapImpl.java:76)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.TypeMapStore.getOrCreate(TypeMapStore.java:110)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.addMappings(ModelMapper.java:93)
    at com.ibm.calypso.service.CompanyServiceImpl.updateIdentificationIdfn(CompanyServiceImpl.java:48)
    at com.ibm.calypso.controller.CompanyController.updateIdentificationIdfn(CompanyController.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.ibm.calypso.filter.CORSFilter.doFilterInternal(CORSFilter.java:29)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The error had already been raised but no one seems to have responded to it.

https://github.com/jhalterman/modelmapper/issues/103

My code structure is similar to the one in the link.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am not sure if you found a solution to this already. But I did a work around to get past this problem.
I was doing modelMapper.addMappings(myPropertymap) in my service method. So it  tries to add mappings for every incoming request. I added the below check to make sure it adds only if the mapping doesn't exist already

```
// Before
modelMapper.addMappings(myPropertyMap);


// After
TypeMap<Source, Dest> typeMap = modelMapper.getTypeMap(Source.class, Dest.class);
if (typeMap == null) { // if not  already added
   modelMapper.addMappings(myPropertyMap);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, Rakesh. But this problem is now not relevant to me any longer.

Comment: this solution may not work in many cases , how i resolved is to initializes a new ModelMapper Object at the start of method doing mappings.

Answer (score 2):

The above workaround works but with following condition:

`if (typeMap == null) {
   modelMapper.addMappings(myPropertyMap);
}`

With not null condition mapping will never be added to the modelMapper.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question, but I had the same error but for a potentially different reason. Here is the code that was causing problems:

```
private static final ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
{
    PropertyMap<SomeSourceClass, SomeTargetClass> map =
        new PropertyMap<SomeSourceClass, SomeTargetClass>() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                // my configuration
            }
        };
    mapper.addMappings(map);
}
```

The issue was that ModelMapper was a static field, but that my initialization was happening every time that a new object of this class was created, the correct code uses a [static initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) instead:

```
private static final ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
static {
    PropertyMap<SomeSourceClass, SomeTargetClass> map =
        new PropertyMap<SomeSourceClass, SomeTargetClass>() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                // my configuration
            }
        };
    mapper.addMappings(map);
}
```

Hope this can help someone with the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answers supplied by horizon7 and RakeshB. Two issues:

1. It's a workaround, not a fix
2. It didn't work for me, unfortunately.
   2.1. Disclaimer, had it worked for me I wouldn't have raised this

Anyways, further searching showed me that this is because the model mapper must be a singleton. On the first request after launching the application, it will work well, on the second request, the mapper will try to add a mapping that already exists and will thus throw the error.

When it's a Singleton, it will always be a new mapper on every request

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65346728/2918731

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was because of adding twice `createTypeMap` for same object!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
TypeMap<Source, Dest> typeMap = modelMapper.typeMap(Source.class, Dest.class);
```

> Returns the TypeMap for the sourceType, destinationType, creates
> TypeMap automatically if none exists. Throws: IllegalArgumentException
> – is sourceType, destinationType are null